# java - JsonMessage is ok in server side but returns error 500 to client

Tags: java, json, spring

I do a ajax call to get a list of items but it returns HTTP error 500.
I traced it in server and map is populated without error. No exception is thrown.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "some/path", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public JsonMessage getlist(@RequestParam(value = "id") Long id){
    MyObject myobject = myObjectManager.get(id);

    Map map =  new HashMap<>();
    map.put("shits",lottery.getMultipleRewards());

    return JsonMessage.Success(map);
}
```

any ideas?

(If the map is empty or I set something static like a string on it then it works).

Comment: Is there any error messages in the server logfiles?

Comment: I'd be amazed if there is absolutely no exception thrown but you still get an HTTP 500 response.  Have you checked _all_ the server log files?

Comment: I now just triple-checked the logs and there is no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happening with particularly demanding implementations when the client didn't include the proper `Accept: application/json` header or the server didn't include the `Content-Type: application/json`.

Since the error occurs outside of your code the logging might be generated in an unexpected way/place and you might have suppressed that particular logger.

Another thing that I can think of is that you might be proxy-ing the request through another server. In this case the server that handles the request can generate a correct response but the proxy throws an error for some reason.

Comment: All assumptions of course. Would be helpful to post an entire request/reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try return a string
2. if works try simplest object(**with xml root**)
3. if it works try to return single object without root.
4. if it works try map of strings
5. check if all loggers are set correctly.
   Your configuration and used technology might be helpful in diagnose.